# Is NSMutableArray really a good backing store for stacks or queues?

Tags: objective-c, performance, algorithm, cocoa, nsarray

I've read somewhere that `NSMutableArray` will have O(1) performance instead of O(n) when elements are added/removed from the ends of the array (e.g. `removeAtObject:0` or `removeLastObject`) which makes it suitable for use as a stack or queue – negating the need to create a LinkedList implementation for those container types.

Is it really the case? If so, how Apple managed to do this? If not, is there any evidence showing that the time taken to add/remove elements at either end of `NSMutableArray` instances increases as the number of elements in the array increase?

PS: Since `NSMutableArray` is essentially `CFArray` (it's "pure-C" counterpart), and [the source code to `CFArray` is open](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFArray.c), it should be possible to inspect its inner workings.

Comment: I don't know what the precise performance points are -- I doubt that it's always O(1), but the implementation is "smart" and I suspect it uses a sort of linked list of arrays to make the performance fairly "steady".

Comment: Linked lists have poor locality of reference and fragmentation properties. Amortized O(1) can be achieved without them.

Comment: Some empirical exploration: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Comment: Note that that blog post predates the current implementation of NSMutableArray. Still a fantastic post though :)

Comment: What makes you sure that NSArray & NSMutableArray are implemented at all with CFArray and CFMutableArray??!

Comment: They used to be, but aren't anymore. It was (and is) easy to confirm with a debugger. No need to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_NSArrayM (which is used instead of CFArray for most NSArrays) is currently an array-deque, which does provide amortized O(1) push/pop at both ends

(This is not guaranteed to be this way on any past or future OS version. NSArrayM itself is quite new for example)

Comment: Any verifiable evidence / test results on this?

Comment: You could try disassembling it with Hopper I suppose. Otherwise, I'm afraid not. My NDA prevents me from providing much.

Comment: Btw, your source code from this blog post is missing: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html – care to put it on Github? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not the author of that post, though I do know him. Try pinging him on twitter? He's @ridiculous_fish

Comment: Here's great investigations for that: http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/

Answer (score 1):

`CFArray`/`CFMutableArray` (and by extension, `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`) have *very* loose performance guarantees---they certainly don't guarantee O(1) insert/delete performance.

From `CFArray.h` (emphasis added):

> Computational Complexity
>   The access time for a value in the array is
>   guaranteed to be at   worst O(lg N) for any implementation, current and
>   future, but will  often be O(1) (constant time). Linear search
>   operations similarly  have a worst case complexity of O(N*lg N),
>   though typically the  bounds will be tighter, and so on. **Insertion or
>   deletion operations   will typically be linear in the number of values
>   in the array, but     may be O(N*lg N) clearly in the worst case in some
>   implementations.  There are no favored positions within the array for
>   performance;  that is, it is not necessarily faster to access values
>   with low  indices, or to insert or delete values with high indices, or
>     whatever.**

Core Foundation/Foundation doesn't currently provide any data structures that model the performance of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth using Obj-C++ and use any of the STL/boost containers if the datastore is used on its own (i.e. not used as backing store for tree/array controllers).